# How to get selected radio button in group via c#?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, radio-button

How to get the index of the selected Radiobutton control that is located inside a panel (parent container) via c#?

The control of Radiobuttons is named "acc" if that is needed for the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you are looking to get the currently selected radio button from a number of radio buttons on a single control?

Comment: Yes I do.I have a stackpanel and RadionButtons inside it(from 1 to 10 buttons of group "acc") and need to get selected RadioButton.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Vertical">
        <RadioButton x:Name="1"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="2"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="3"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="4"></RadioButton>
        ...
        <RadioButton x:Name="10"></RadioButton>
</StackPanel>

for (int i = 0; i < this.panel.Children.Count; i++)
{
    if (this.panel.Children[i].GetType().Name == "RadioButton")
    {
        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)this.panel.Children[i];
        if ((bool)radio.IsChecked)
        {
            this.txt.Text ="the check radio button is:"+ radio.Name.ToString();
        }
    }
 }
```

The index of the button selected would be the value of "i" that corresponds to (bool)radio.IsChecked being true, so you may just record this value and use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Even easier version

```
        foreach (RadioButton rb in YourStackPanel.Children)
        {
            if (rb.IsChecked == true)
            {
                //Do whatever you need with it.
            }
        }
```